# What could be reasons a WPF app would pin the CPU and lock the app on some computers but not others?

Tags: wpf, multithreading

Stumped here.  Posted a similar question before.  We have a pretty large WPF app that on some machines runs great, but on others, all of a sudden, one of the CPU cores gets pinned at 100% (just one core) and the app freezes.  It usually seems to happen when showing a context menu or a combobox drop-down (i.e. Popup controls) which is why we can't debug this since no user code is executing at that time.  It's driving us crazy because again, on most machines it runs fine, but on a few, it freezes.

The odd thing is when we run it in a VM, it runs great there too!  Crazy!  Not sure what's causing this, or more importantly, where to even begin to look because as I said, no user code is running.

This happens on only about 10% of our machines, but it consistently happens on those machines.  All are clean (i.e. relatively fresh OS installs, no crazy apps, etc.) and mostly identical machines spec-wise: similar CPUs, similar RAM, same video drivers and service packs.

So as I stated in the title, can anyone suggest possible reasons why a WPF app would pin the CPU and lock the app on some computers but not others?  We're just stumped!

Comment: context menu defined in xaml or code behind or both ? maybe show some code. Same question for ComboBox. Did you try with very simple Context menu / ComboBox ? and since both are pop ups, did you try just showing a pop up to see if this is the core issue ? might be graphic card/graphic driver related since on VM graphic management change, but you stated that both graphic settings are same... Maybe (again to see where issue is coming from) try force the software rendering.

Comment: No code to show.  Simple standard context menu with a few attached commands.  Checked the 'CanExecute' handlers and there's nothing odd going on in there either.  Besides, they don't exist with a combo box.  BTW, I'm purely guessing about the Popup but that does seem to be a common thing.  Still, again, when this happens, everything freezes up, even VS.  If it were a code issue, I should still be able to break into it.  It's not a VS issue either as this also happens with the installed app with no VS to be found.  Happens on about 5-10% of our machines, but consistently on them.

Comment: The [WPF Performance Suite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969767.aspx) has some tools that might help you isolate the source of the problem.

Comment: We actually have the Red Gate performance suite which, from my understanding, is a big step-up from that, but even their support personnel said they can help with profiling code and analyzing performance and memory leaks, but code hangs where it's not even user code is a real pain to find out.  We've even tried to use MS's source code option inside VS to step into their code to see what was going on, but still, no dice.

Comment: how "heavy" is the graphics underneath your context menu?  i have an app that had a lot of images, video and semi transparent gradients and reflections going on.  it gave poor performance on some machines.  In the end i found that reflections that used a gradient alpha were a big slow down.

Comment: Not heavy at all.  Actually its mostly just listboxes and treeviews.  Again, it's not that it's slow... it's that it pins the CPU and hangs.  We've waited several minutes and it doesn't come back.  Our next step is just to wait even longer to see if it's a true hang or not (we're thinking 'not' because the CPU core gets pinned, not falls to zero.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it!!  Turns out there's a bug in .NET 4.0 regarding UI Automation and the changes MS introduced.  Here's the info, and the fix! (Note: Even if you call MS, they will send you a link, but it's always a broken link.  I managed to track this down manually.)

Note: Their article talks about a specific case that causes this behavior, but if you google around, you'll see tons of issues around hangs related to those DLLs.  The latest is they're promising a fix in the .NET 4.5 runtime (from a MS post on this issue.)

Here's the KB article...
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2484841/en-us

...and here is the actual hotfix.
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB2484841/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=5583

Comment: Two deadlinks. :-(

Comment: Try googling the KB itself: `microsoft kb 2484841`

Answer (score 0):

Crappy video driver? Pull two machines - one where it happens, one where not, and start analyzing differences. Could be hardware defects, bad video drivers, anything in that area. WPF uses the GPU to render if one is there.

Comment: Yeah, as I said above, we've already tried that.  Even on almost-identical notebooks where I believe even the video card is the exact same, same driver which we even re-installed just in case, it still happens on one and not the other.  We're really stumped here.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem quite to lack options, i would advice to make a new project with just most basic ComboBox in the Window, doing almost nothing. This should work (check :-) ). Then you add features one by one in the ComboBox and test, for instance when you add command, start with empty one. Do this until it 'breaks'. So you know which feature is the culprit.
You didn t say if all was working with software rendering.

Comment: Rendering is fine.  And this application was created with a team of 20 people over three years.  We're getting ready to release.  Even doing the reverse of what you say is incredibly time-consuming on the order of weeks or even months.  There's just so much going on in this app... mostly processor-intensive, not UI-intensive.  Still, the app is snappy, then you right-click on something, and bam! Wall.

Comment: i understand that you have a big app. But for the test test i suggest no need for quality code / source control / ... Doing plain simple file copy / Cut-n-paste until the bug shows surely does not take months or week.  
another similar idea might be to populate litlle by little (starting by nothing) a ComboBox Within your app, using model class(es) having same interface but doing 'nothing', and wire one by one the functions to the 'real' ones. this mapping could be enabled or not one by one by a list of checkboxes in the interface.