# How to disable WPF UI Automation?

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, ui-automation

I have a .NET 4.0 WPF application that has to run in parallel with another application which is a screen reader (not for accessibility reasons), which is activating WPF's UI Automation.

This is causing memory consumption of the application to be nearly double than normal.

Is there a way to turn this off, or a reliable workaround for this?

I have had a good Google,  but I couldn't find any work around that would fix the problem. As the majority of the posts were fairly old I figured something may have changed in the last couple of years...

Comment: Have you checked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028598/what-could-be-reasons-a-wpf-app-would-pin-the-cpu-and-lock-the-app-on-some-compu

Comment: That 'fix' is one of the few fixes I have been able to try due to broken links.

Comment: The fix is available here I think: http://thehotfixshare.net/board/index.php?showtopic=15676

Comment: I think this has already been applied to the version of .net 4.0 I have. As the listed .dll for Presensationframework is 4.0.30319.439, and my version is 4.0.30319.18060.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/93e295aa-4531-47ce-b503-f8506e249fea/uiautomation-degrades-wpf-application-performance?forum=wpf (the answer about the WM_OBJECT hack)